# In Vim, replace all occurrences of current term under cursor

Tags: vim

If you press <kbd>*</kbd> in Vim, the editor will search for the next occurrence of the term in the same file. It saves you from having to type out the term.

Is there a quick way to replace the term currently under the cursor with a new one? One character to issue the command, typing in the new term, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: You can also use **n** for **next** match, and **b** for **back** (previous) match.

Comment: @Orwellophile only `n` works for me `b` goes back to default (beginning of the word) `#` works for me as expected, which goes back to the previous term.

Comment: @JohnnyQ sorry Johnny, I must have been high on glue.  it's `n` for next and `N` for previous.   It's written on my keyboard so I don't know how I got it wrong.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use:

```
:%s/<c-r><c-w>/new value/g
```

where `<c-r><c-w>` means to literally type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to insert the word under the cursor.

Comment: it'd be goot explaining the meaning of each command here :)

Comment: Only 12 years later, to understand the `<C-r><C-w>` form, and similar forms, you can type `:help c_<C-R>_<C-W>` and look at vim's help on it.

Answer (score 172):

Just use <kbd>*</kbd> to search for the word under your cursor and then:

```
:%s//new value/g
```

This will (*s*)ubstitute all instances of the word under the cursor with `new value`.

When you don't specify a search pattern between the `//` characters, the substitute command uses the last searched pattern.

The `g` at the end will replace all match instances in each line (default without `g` is to replace only the first match). If you don't want to specify `g` every time, [you can configure `gdefault`](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/eh84vk/setting_to_have_search_and_replace_default_to/) (but heed the warnings that it can break plugins that don't account for it).

Comment: And if `new value` contains an `&` or a `/`, just escape it with `\\`.

Comment: @sjas What does :se gd do?

Comment: `:se gd` or `:set gdefault` tells vim to treat every pattern as if it had a /g modifier at the end (more precisely, it inverts the meaning of the /g flag, so if you use it with `gdefault` active it will disable the effect)

Comment: What if I had the to use the searched word in the string that I am replacing it with. e.g. if the word under my cursor is `function_with_a_long_name` and I have to replace all it's instances with `self.function_with_a_long_name` ?

Comment: @ParthSharma to do this, you can use the default "capture group" `\0` which in this case contains the term you pressed `*` on, so for your example, you'd use the command:

`:%s//self.\0/g`

Comment: To interactively *c*onfirm (or deny) each substitution, append substitution parameter *c*:

`%s//new_value/gc`

Common use case: if the goal is to rename all instances of a variable, but the variable name is a word that might also appear in docstrings as a word and not as a reference to that variable (e.g. `limit`, `color`, `message`).

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the other answers, you could shave off some more keystrokes by adding following snippet to your .vimrc file for doing a global search and replace.

```
" Search and replace word under cursor using F4
nnoremap <F4> :%s/<c-r><c-w>/<c-r><c-w>/gc<c-f>$F/i
```

Comment: i love it, best answer on the whole internet for me so far ;)

Comment: 12 years later, this is the best solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: what does the part at the end do? this part: <c-f>$F/i

Comment: @john_m_kenny - the `<c-f>` opens the current command in a new buffer where you can edit the command just like you would edit text. The `$` sets the cursor to the end of the line. The `F` searches backwards for a `/` and the `i` puts you in insert mode, ready to change the replacement value.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and whipped up a plugin which lets you just enter the following:

```
:Dr REPLACEVALUE
```

https://github.com/chiedojohn/vim-dr-replace

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `gn`:

> Search forward for the last used search pattern, like with
>   `n`, and start Visual mode to select the match.
>   If the cursor is on the match, visually selects it.
>   If an operator is pending, operates on the match.
>   E.g., "dgn" deletes the text of the next match.
>   If Visual mode is active, extends the selection until the end of the
>   next match.
>   Note: Unlike `n` the search direction does not depend on the previous search command.

So if you have `FOO` as last search expression, you can replace its next match with `BAR` typing `cgnBAR<Esc>`, and repeat for the following matches with `.`.

If you want to set the word under the cursor as search expression you can type `*N` (or `*#`) to search for the next match and come back.

For example, if your cursor is under the first `FOO` in this line:

```
<div class="FOO"><span id="FOO"><b>FOO:</b> FOO</span></div>
```

and you type `*NcgnBAR<Esc>...`, you end up with this:

```
<div class="BAR"><span id="BAR"><b>BAR:</b> BAR</span></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution for supervised substitution and I find it more elegant than typing the equivalent explicit search substitution command `:%s//BAR/gc`. Deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature I also desired! But not only for the word under the cursor, also for a visual selection or a motion.

As a result (and building up on your answers), I added this to my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :set operatorfunc=SubstituteOperator<cr>g@
vnoremap <leader>g :<c-u>call SubstituteOperator(visualmode())<cr>

function! SubstituteOperator(type)
    if a:type ==# 'v'
        execute 'normal! `<v`>"my'
    elseif a:type ==# 'char'
        execute 'normal! `[v`]"my'
    else
        return
    endif

    let sub = input("substitute '".getreg("m")."' with ... : ")
    execute "%s/".getreg("m")."/".sub."/gc"
endfunction
```

I can now press things like `\sw`, `\sf;` or `\si(` in normal mode or `\s` in visual mode and get prompt asking if what I want to substitute my selection with.

(So far I don't know if I want the same prompt as @Lieven...)